# Implementing quicksort in a functional way

Tags: python, quicksort

I've just wrote Python quicksort - I wish I have the shortest way to do this (quite like functional way), so I wrote:

```
def quicksort(List):
    if len(List)>1:
        Pivot=List[0]            
        return quicksort(lessThan(List,Pivot)) + [Pivot] + quicksort(moreThan(List,Pivot))
    else:
        return List

def lessThan(List, Pivot):
    lessThanList = [x for x in List if x <= Pivot]
    return lessThanList

def moreThan(List, Pivot):
    moreThanList = [x for x in List if x > Pivot]
    return moreThanList
```

Unfortunately, it skips all multi-appearance of numbers. Ok, it seems logic, but when I've tried to improve that writing:

```
def lessThan(List, Pivot):
    lessThanList = [x for x in List if x <= Pivot]
    return lessThanList
```

It turns out to be infinite loop which is completely understandable for me. Could somebody point me out what is wrong?

Comment: What's the minimum data to cause the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, your oversight was that you were not removing the pivot when you partitioned your lists. If you like writing in a functional style, Python offers expressive language constructs,
 like [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), that we can take advantage that would have helped avoid the easy mistake:

```
def quicksort(seq):
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        return seq
    pivot, *rest = seq
    smaller = quicksort([x for x in rest if x <= pivot])
    larger = quicksort([x for x in rest if x > pivot])
    return smaller + [pivot] + larger
```

In action:

```
>>> quicksort([10,2,5,3,1,6,7,4,2,3,4,8,9])
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: It's a good answer, except the code you posted suffers infinite recursion on the example you gave.  You're only calling `quicksort` _once_ at the end.  Should be `return quicksort(smaller) + [pivot] + quicksort(larger)` instead.

Comment: @TimPeters yeah, I copied it over from my shell session incorrectly. Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the first element as the pivot, the simplest way to prevent infinite recursion is to avoid passing the first element to `lessThan`.  Add two characters like so:

```
return quicksort(lessThan(List[1:],Pivot)) + ...
                               ^^
```

Clear?  It passes the list *except* for the first element (the pivot).

Note, though, that you can still get recursion about equal to the length of the original list; for example, imagine sorting `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Any additional items that are equal to `pivot` get lost - neither your lessThan nor moreThan lists will contain them, and you only insert the one instance of `[pivot]` between the two sublists.  Changing `lessThan` to use `<=` opens you up to a possible infinite recursion; at every step the sublists must be strictly smaller than the original list, or you're not making any progress.  One approach would be:

```
return quicksort(lessThan(List,pivot)) + equalTo(List,pivot) + quicksort(moreThan(List,pivot))
```

where `equalTo()` works just like your existing `lessThan()` & `moreThan()`.